# Items being searched depend on previous result

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I’m pretty new to Vue and have recently dug into Vuex. I’m attempting to search through an API. The initial search works as intended. However, if a search is performed with a different query, only what was previously returned is searched through.

For example, if I searched ‘ve’, both ‘Vettel’ and ‘Verstappen’ would return as expected. However if I then search for anything without the letters previously returned, nothing appears, e.g. ‘ham’ when searching for Hamilton afterwards would not return anything.

I've tried modifying the mutations, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Here’s the component:

```
<template>
  <transition
    appear
    appear-class="fade-enter"
    appear-to-class="fade-enter-to"
    appear-active-class="fade-enter-active"
  >
    <div>
      <h3>Current Standings</h3>

      <input type="text" v-model="searchQuery" v-on:input="search" placeholder="search driver">

      <table class="standings">
        <thead>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Driver Name</th>
          <th>Nationality</th>
          <th>Team</th>
          <th>Wins</th>
          <th>Points</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="standing in ALL_STANDINGS" :key="standing.position" class="standing">
            <td>{{standing.position }}</td>
            <td>{{standing.Driver.driverId | last-name | to-title-case}}</td>
            <td>{{standing.Driver.nationality | to-title-case}}</td>
            <td>{{standing.Constructors[0].constructorId | to-title-case}}</td>
            <td>{{standing.wins }}</td>
            <td>{{standing.points}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
import styles from "../styles/styles.scss";
import { mapState, mapGetters, mapActions, mapMutations } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "CurrentStandings",

  data() {
    return {
      searchQuery: ""
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.fetchStandings();
  },

  mounted() {
    this.created = true;
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState(["standings", "filter"]),
    ...mapGetters(["ALL_STANDINGS", "GET_SEARCH", "FILTERED_SEARCH"])
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchStandings"]),
    ...mapMutations(["SET_SEARCH", "SET_FILTER"]),

    search: function() {
      // set SEARCH to input
      this.$store.commit("SET_SEARCH", this.searchQuery);
      // return matches between ALL_STANDINGS and SEARCH
      this.SET_FILTER(
        this.ALL_STANDINGS.filter(standing => {
          return standing.Driver.driverId.match(this.GET_SEARCH);
        })
      );
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

and here’s the standings.js module:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
  standings: [],
  filter: [],
  search: '',
};

const getters = {
  /* eslint no-shadow: ["error", { "allow": ["state"] }] */
  ALL_STANDINGS: state => state.standings,
  FILTERED_STANDINGS: state => state.filter,
  GET_SEARCH: state => state.search,

};

const mutations = {
  SET_STANDINGS: (state, standings) => (state.standings = standings),
  SET_SEARCH: (state, search) => (state.search = search),
  SET_FILTER: (state, filter) => (state.standings = filter),
  RESET_STANDINGS: (state, standings) => (state.filter = standings),

};


const actions = {
  async fetchStandings({ commit }) {
    const response = await axios.get('https://ergast.com/api/f1/current/driverStandings.json');

    commit('SET_STANDINGS', response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings); // response.data is passed to 'standings' in the mutation (2nd arg)
  },

};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks :)

Comment: Where is `this.searchQuery` defined? I see you using it, but don't see it initialized anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited the post to include the full component, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify initial dataset when performing filtering:

```
  SET_FILTER: (state, filter) => (state.standings = filter),
```

should be

```
  SET_FILTER: (state, filter) => (state.filter = filter),
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind helping me out with the method?  `search: function() {
      // set SEARCH to input
      this.$store.commit("SET_SEARCH", this.searchQuery);
      // return matches between ALL_STANDINGS and SEARCH
      this.SET_FILTER(
        this.ALL_STANDINGS.filter(standing => {
          return (
            !this.GET_SEARCH || this.FILTERED_STANDINGS,
            console.log(typeof this.FILTERED_STANDINGS)
          );
        })
      ); `

Comment: Sorry for the formatting above! The code can be found on my [Github](https://github.com/Freeptom/Formula_One/blob/search/src/components/CurrentStandings.vue)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using simplifying the project with fewer mutations and used getters, rather than modifying the state directly:

```
  data() {
    return {
      searchQuery: "",
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.fetchStandings();
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState(["standings", "search", "filter"]),
    ...mapGetters(["filteredStandings", "sortedFilteredStandings"])
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchStandings"]),
    ...mapMutations(["SET_SEARCH"]),

    filterStandings() {
      this.$store.commit("SET_SEARCH", this.searchQuery);
    }
  }
```

The store:

```
const state = {
  standings: [],
  search: '',
};

const getters = {

  filteredStandings: state => state.standings.filter(standing => standing.Driver.driverId.match(state.search)),
};

const mutations = {
  SET_STANDINGS: (state, standings) => (state.standings = standings),
  SET_SEARCH: (state, search) => (state.search = search),
};
```